# C# - Deserialize a JSON string with two arrays?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am using C# to retrieve JSON data. The JSON has two arrays, one for rental cars and one for company cars, and then each car has two pieces of data. JSON output is like the follwing

```
{"companycars":[[VIN,LICENSEPLATE],[VIN,LICENSEPLATE],"rentalcars":[[VIN,LICENSEPLATE],[VIN,LICENSEPLATE]]}
```

I am using JSON.net and can handle one array to deserialize to a simple string Dictionary with something like

```
Dictionary<string, string> allCars = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(myCars);
```

But what is the example for two arrays within the same result? I want to basically end up with two dictionary (string) objects.

Comment: you mean like Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>?

Comment: Or do you mean one dictionary for Company Cars and One for rental cars>

Comment: Either one would be fine actually. I just need to end up with 2 string dictionaries at some point - I can parse it many ways after that.

Comment: @Jeremy I tried this suggestion and the JSON.net object still throws an error. I tried it as Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>> allCars = JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectDictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>(myCars);

Comment: Here's a tip: Serialize your desired structure to JSON with emitting full type info `TypeNameHandling.All` and see how the JSON looks like. Its sort of reverse engineering but is helpful at times like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a class to store the result of your de serialised JSON like so:

```
public class Cars
{
    public List<string[]> Companycars { get; set; }
    public List<string[]> Rentalcars { get; set; }

    public Cars()
    {
        Rentalcars = new List<string[]>();
        Companycars = new List<string[]>();
    }
}
```

---

```
string myCars = "{\"companycars\":[[\"VIN\",\"LICENSEPLATE\"],[\"VIN\",\"LICENSEPLATE\"]],\"rentalcars\":[[\"VIN\",\"LICENSEPLATE\"],[\"VIN\",\"LICENSEPLATE\"]]}";
Cars allCars = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cars>(myCars);
```

Hope this helps.

---

**Edit:**

If you don't need to pass the object around you could store the result into an anonymous type:

```
var allCars = new
{
    CompanyCars = new List<string[]>(),
    RentalCars = new List<string[]>()
};

string myCars = "{\"companycars\":[[\"VIN\",\"LICENSEPLATE\"],[\"VIN\",\"LICENSEPLATE\"]],\"rentalcars\":[[\"VIN\",\"LICENSEPLATE\"],[\"VIN\",\"LICENSEPLATE\"]]}";

allCars = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(myCars, allCars);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to avoid this step since they're all simple strings but it sounds like this is going to be one of my few options for this